# Python - Files wont download

Tags: python, wxpython, urllib

Here's My code, all the urls are in a Config Parser format file. When the button is pressed files will not download. What did go wrong? I used urllib should I have used urllib2? Some of the functions may be there but not used just ignore that.

```
import wx
import ConfigParser
import urllib

def Download(url):
    response = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    doned = wx.MessageDialog("Download Done")
    doned.ShowModal()
    doned.Destroy()

#First thing i gona do is Parse 98 box data
BoxParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser() #Set Raw
BoxParser.read("98.box") #Mount into 98.box
#Get Vars, and print them

WxTitle = BoxParser.get("meta_data","Window_title") #get the window title
Application = BoxParser.get("meta_data","Application") #Get app name
Desc = BoxParser.get("meta_data","Description") #Get the description of the app
Author = BoxParser.get("meta_data","Author") #Of course! I dont wanna be plagurized
Contact = BoxParser.get("meta_data","Contact_Info") #My Contact Info
Date = BoxParser.get("meta_data","Date") #Date when the current update was made
#UpdateUrl = BoxParser.get("meta_data","Update_url") #Url to update
#BoxUp = BoxParser.get("meta_data","Update_box") #Url to update 98.box
# Meta Data loaded

#time to load the firmwares
e660 = BoxParser.get("Firmware_links","660") #6.60
e6602 = False
e660g = BoxParser.get("Firmware_links","660go") #6.60 Go Eboot
e6602g = False
e639 = BoxParser.get("Firmware_links","639") #6.39
e6392 = False
e639g = BoxParser.get("Firmware_links","639go") #6.39 Go Eboot
e6392g = False
e635 = BoxParser.get("Firmware_links","635") #6.35
e6352 = False
e635g = BoxParser.get("Firmware_links","635go") #6.35 Go Eboot
e6352g = False
e620 = BoxParser.get("Firmware_links","620") #6.20
e550 = BoxParser.get("Firmware_links","550") #5.50
e5502 = False
e500 = BoxParser.get("Firmware_links","500") #5.00
e5002 = False
e401 = BoxParser.get("Firmware_links","401") #4.01
e4012 = False
#Firmwares Loaded








def BoxUpdate():
    Download(Update_box)
    #Check if DD equ true so we can post the MSG
    if downloaddone == True:
        Done2 = wx.MessageDialog(self,"Download Done, 98.Box Updated!")
        Done2.ShowModal()
        Done.Destroy()


#Time to get out Gui
class FrameClass(wx.Frame): #Finally making the gui!
    def __init__(self,parent,title): #making init!
        app = wx.Frame
        app.__init__(self,parent,title=WxTitle,size = (340,280)) #set window size

        Menu = wx.Menu() #Lets make a menu!
        panel = wx.Panel(self) #set the panel var

        contact = Menu.Append(wx.ID_NONE,"&Contact Info") #add update thing
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.contact1,contact) #Add event for Update
        fwMsg = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Firmware', pos=(59,25))
        fwlist = wx.ComboBox(panel,pos=(118,22), choices=["6.60","6.60 Go/N1000","6.39","6.39 Go/N1000","6.35 Go/N1000","5.50","5.00","4.01"])
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.getsel, fwlist)
        downloadbutton = wx.Button(panel, label="Download FW", pos=(100,76))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.DLB, downloadbutton)

        #now for the member!
        TopM = wx.MenuBar()
        TopM.Append(Menu, "Tool Opt")
        self.SetMenuBar(TopM)
        self.Show(True)

    def DLUpdate(self,e):
        #Check if DD equ true so we can post the MSG
        Download(Update_url)
        print "downloading"

        Done = wx.MessageDialog(self,"Download Done, download stored in \"DLBOXV$.zip\" file")
        Done.ShowModal()
        Done.Destroy()

    def contact1(self,e):
        con = wx.MessageDialog(self,Contact)
        con.ShowModal()
        con.Destroy()


    def getsel(self,e):
        i = e.GetString()
        if i == "6.60":
            e6602 = True
            print e6602,"660"
        else:
            e6602 = False
            print e6602,"660"

        if i == "6.60 Go/N1000":
            e6602g = True
            print e6602g,"660 go"
        else:
            e6602g = False
            print e6602g,"660 go"

        if i == "6.39":
            e6392 = True
            print e6392,"639"
        else:
            e6392 = False
            print e6392,"639"

        if i == "6.39 Go/N1000":
            e6392g = True
            print e6392g,"639 go"
        else:
            e6392g = False
            print e6392g,"639 go"

        if i == "6.35 Go/N1000":
            e6352g = False
            print e6352g,"635 go"
        else:
            e6352g = False
            print e6352g,"635 go"

        if i == "5.50":
            e5502 = True
            print e5502,"550"
        else:
            e5502 = False
            print e5502,"550"

        if i == "500":
            e5002 = True
            print e5002,"500"
        else:
            e5002 = False
            print e5002,"500"

        if i == "401":
            e4012 = True
            print e4012,"401"
        else:
            e4012 = False
            print e4012,"401"



    def DLB(self,e):
        if e6602 == True:
            Download(e660)
        elif e6602g == True:
            Download(e660g)
        elif e6392 == True:
            Download(e639)
        elif e639g == True:
            Download(e639g)
        elif e6352g == True:
            Download(e635g)
        elif e5502 == True:
            Download(e550)
        elif e5002 == True:
            Download(e500)
        elif e4012 == True:
            Download(e401)

G = wx.App(False)
Win = FrameClass(None,WxTitle)
G.MainLoop()
```

But at the function `Download(url)` will not function, it will not download

```
def Download(url):
        response = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        doned = wx.MessageDialog("Download Done")
        doned.ShowModal()
        doned.Destroy()
```

what triggers `Download(url)` is a few if and elsif statements

```
def getsel(self,e):
            i = e.GetString()
            if i == "6.60":
                e6602 = True
                print e6602,"660"
            else:
                e6602 = False
                print e6602,"660"

            if i == "6.60 Go/N1000":
                e6602g = True
                print e6602g,"660 go"
            else:
                e6602g = False
                print e6602g,"660 go"

            if i == "6.39":
                e6392 = True
                print e6392,"639"
            else:
                e6392 = False
                print e6392,"639"

            if i == "6.39 Go/N1000":
                e6392g = True
                print e6392g,"639 go"
            else:
                e6392g = False
                print e6392g,"639 go"

            if i == "6.35 Go/N1000":
                e6352g = False
                print e6352g,"635 go"
            else:
                e6352g = False
                print e6352g,"635 go"

            if i == "5.50":
                e5502 = True
                print e5502,"550"
            else:
                e5502 = False
                print e5502,"550"

            if i == "500":
                e5002 = True
                print e5002,"500"
            else:
                e5002 = False
                print e5002,"500"

            if i == "401":
                e4012 = True
                print e4012,"401"
            else:
                e4012 = False
                print e4012,"401"



        def DLB(self,e):
            if e6602 == True:
                Download(e660)
            elif e6602g == True:
                Download(e660g)
            elif e6392 == True:
                Download(e639)
            elif e639g == True:
                Download(e639g)
            elif e6352g == True:
                Download(e635g)
            elif e5502 == True:
                Download(e550)
            elif e5002 == True:
                Download(e500)
            elif e4012 == True:
                Download(e401)
```

Comment: Trim your code down to a minimal example that still exhibits your issue.

Comment: Yes, you should have used `urllib2`, given that `urllib` is deprecated and you're not using any of the functionality that isn't trivially portable from one to the other. However, the odds of that having anything to do with your problem seem very tiny.

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestions and comments.

Comment: @abarnert you solved my prob, ty

Answer (score 0):

> What did go wrong? I used urllib should I have used urllib2?

Yes.  The fact that just adding the `2` to your code fixes the problem is obviously proof of that, but it doesn't explain much.

As the docs for [`urllib.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) say:

> Deprecated since version 2.6: The `urlopen()` function has been removed in Python 3 in favor of `urllib2.urlopen()`.

This doesn't mean that they stopped fixing bugs in `urllib` as of 2.6 (there was a bug fix as late as 2.7.9), but it does mean that missing functionality will never be added. That includes, among other things, some kinds of HTTP authentication, redirections, HTTPS with non-standard CAs, proxy settings, and proxy authentication.

Without knowing anything at all about the problem besides "the download doesn't happen", or what URL you're trying to download (you seem to be passing in a variable named `Update_box` that isn't assigned anywhere), or the setup you're running on, it's impossible to know exactly which one of these problems (or any others) is the key.